# What is register_rest_route's callback's $data variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is really bizarre. I've spent at least 5 hours trying to figure out what this $data variable truly is and what is in it. I think the question is a little confusing, so let me explain what I'm talking about:

The callback for register_rest_route is a function that takes one parameter, $data, which seems to be a magical object. I've been trying to follow the source to figure out if there's something more to this. Could someone explain? It could be very illuminating for the community (OK, or at least me).

```
register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/customer/', array(
  'methods'   => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'get_stuff',
) );
```

So, my function `get_stuff` looks like this:

```
get_stuff( $data ) {
  return array(
    'is object? ' . is_object( $data ), // returns 1
    'is array? ' . is_array( $data ), // returns blank; nothing
    get_object_vars( $data ), // returns an empty array
    $data, // returns {}; an empty object
    $data['assignee'], // returns POST'd data as expected
    $data['number'], // returns POST'd data as expected
    $data->number  // returns null; I thought this was an object? Why doesn't this work?
}
```

What the is `$data`?

For the longest time, I was trying to return the entire $data object, just to test/debug/play, and was getting an empty object, until I tried getting one of the properties. I'm thoroughly confused because it doesn't behave like an object, but apparently is one. I can't seem to get it in its entirety, but only if I specify a property. Can someone clear this up?

Comment: What does get_class($data) yield?

Comment: @colburton 'WP_REST_Request'

Comment: I can use print_r too and actually get the entire object, which I didn't reply because I didn't think Postman would accept it for some reason. While this technically answers my question, I just want to understand how getting values from the keys gives me data from an object inside a protected property.

Comment: This works, because the WP_REST_Request implements ArrayAccess, which forces an offsetGet method, which provides exactly this behaviour. See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/

Answer (score 3):

The return type is a WP_REST_REQUEST object, so in order to get the body of the request you will have to invoke the get_body method.

```
function get_stuff( $data ) {
    $result = $data->get_body(); //returns a string of the body
    return $result;
}
```

However, if you're like me, you'll most likely be sending JSON in a POST request, so invoke the parse_json method to get an object/array.

```
function get_val($data){
    $json_result = json_decode($data->get_body(), true); //note second param is for setting this to an associative array
    $some_value = $json_result["some_var"];
    return $some_value;
}
```

Here's some helpful links:
WP_REST_REQUEST docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/

Parsing JSON: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/json_decode/